# Where should I use thread.sleep in a java swing program?

Tags: java, swing

Right now I've programmed a method for use in a swing program that is supposed to slow down the speed the method it's called in is run (via thread.sleep(x) ) and instead of slowing down the speed of refresh it's just causing the whole program to hang and the screen to refresh at the end of the methods execution.

Here's my code:

```
public final void doBubbleSort(String numbers[], JButton numButton[]){
for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length - 1; k++){  
  String str1 = "";
  boolean isSorted = true;  

  for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length - k; i++){  
     if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]) < Integer.parseInt(numbers[i - 1])  ){  
        try{
        String tempVariable = numbers[i];  
        numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];  
        numbers[i - 1] = tempVariable;  
        isSorted = false; 
        str1 = numButton[i].getText();
        numButton[i].setText(numButton[i-1].getText());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println("Error: " +e.getMessage()); }
        numButton[i-1].setText(str1);
     }   
  }  

  if (isSorted)  
     break;
```

}

}

If anyone can tell me where I should be putting thread.sleep() to make it delay the display of items being swapped I would be greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never sleep in the event dispatch thread.

1. Create a **model**, (in your case a list)
2. Create a **view** (your swing gui)
3. Make sure the view gets updated once the model changes (by adding a **listener** for instance)
4. Create a **separate thread** that updates the model regularly (using `Thread.sleep` if you so like)
5. When changing "speed" **change the sleep times for the updater-thread**

You may want to have a look at the `Timer` class (which provides a nicer interface for doing things at a regular interval) or the Swing Workers.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do animation by putting a loop in an event handler like this. You *must* do it by using a separate thread, either explicitly or by using the `javax.swing.Timer` class. If you loop and sleep on the event thread, as you're doing, then during the entire time the loop is running, the event thread is unavailable to perform its other duties, like painting the screen.

See [this article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/) for information about using the Swing timer class.