# java: why waiting some time is making my program not execute sequentially?

Tags: java, wait, synchronize

I have a GUI that displays a certain iterating process step by step.
I want it to make one step, display the step, wait 1s, and repeat, ...

The code:

```
while (! finished()) {
    advance(); // make and display one step
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {       
    }
}
```

What happens, though, is that nothing is printed until the whole added time of all sleep calls pass, and then all the steps are printed at once.
How can I make the execution flow sequentially?

Note: I tried replacing the sleep call with a very long, useless loop and the behaviour was the same.

Comment: Because you're calling `sleep` in the UI dispatch thread. Possible duplicate of [Where should I use thread.sleep in a java swing program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194721/where-should-i-use-thread-sleep-in-a-java-swing-program)

Comment: Is this a Swing GUI app? How do you display the step?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this task in a separate Thread. You are freezing your gui. You can use `SwingWorker`. Here you have a nice article [Why do we need SwingWorker?](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Note that swingWorker only will execute once. If you want to execute more time you have to take a look for `javax.swing.Timer` also

> Note that the Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch
>   thread. This means that the task can safely manipulate components, but
>   it also means that the task should execute quickly. **If the task might
>   take a while to execute, then consider using a SwingWorker instead of
>   or in addition to the timer.**